# Akka Cluster aware routers - share redis instance to all routee

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

In a context of Akka cluster application, I met an issue about one property expected by Akka : every (cas) class and every message used must be serializable. I have the following context : I want to consume data from a redis cluster and for that, I decided to adopt the cluster aware router pool to add nodes to have more workers. Workers read data from redis and store some metadata in mongodb. In a first version, I did this :

```
object MasterWorkers {

  def props
  (  awsBucket : String,
     gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
     persistentCache: RedisCache,
     mongoURI : String,
     mongoDBName : String,
     mongoCollectioName : String
  ) : Props =
    Props(MasterWorkers(awsBucket, gapMinValueMicroSec, persistentCache, mongoURI, mongoDBName, mongoCollectioName))

  case class JobRemove(deviceId: DeviceId, from : Timestamp, to : Timestamp)
}

case class MasterWorkers
(
  awsBucket : String,
  gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
  persistentCache: RedisCache,
  mongoURI : String,
  mongoDBName : String,
  mongoCollectioName : String
) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val workerRouter =
    context.actorOf(FromConfig.props(Props(classOf[Worker],awsBucket,gapMinValueMicroSec, self, persistentCache, mongoURI, mongoDBName, mongoCollectioName)),
    name = "workerRouter")
```

Worker class :

```
object Worker {

  def props
  (
    awsBucket : String,
    gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
    replyTo : ActorRef,
    persistentCache: RedisCache,
    mongoURI : String,
    mongoDBName : String,
    mongoCollectioName : String
  ) : Props =
    Props(Worker(awsBucket, gapMinValueMicroSec, replyTo, persistentCache, mongoURI, mongoDBName, mongoCollectioName))

  case class JobDumpFailed(deviceId : DeviceId, from: Timestamp, to: Timestamp)
  case class JobDumpSuccess(deviceId : DeviceId, from: Timestamp, to: Timestamp)

  case class JobRemoveFailed(deviceId : DeviceId, from: Timestamp, to: Timestamp)
}

case class Worker
(
  awsBucket : String,
  gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
  replyTo : ActorRef,
  persistentCache: RedisCache,
  mongoURI : String,
  mongoDBName : String,
  mongoCollectioName : String
) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
```

But this raises the below exception when I started two nodes :

```
[info] akka.remote.MessageSerializer$SerializationException: Failed to serialize remote message [class akka.remote.DaemonMsgCreate] using serializer [class akka.remote.serialization.DaemonMsgCreateSerializer].
[info] at akka.remote.MessageSerializer$.serialize(MessageSerializer.scala:61)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:895)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$serializeMessage$1.apply(Endpoint.scala:895)
[info] at scala.util.DynamicVariable.withValue(DynamicVariable.scala:58)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.serializeMessage(Endpoint.scala:894)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointWriter.writeSend(Endpoint.scala:786)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointWriter$$anonfun$4.applyOrElse(Endpoint.scala:761)
[info] at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:497)
[info] at akka.remote.EndpointActor.aroundReceive(Endpoint.scala:452)
[info] at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:526)
[info] at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:495)
[info] at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:257)
[info] at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:224)
[info] at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.exec(Mailbox.scala:234)
[info] at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
[info] at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
[info] at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
[info] at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
[info] Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: akka.actor.ActorSystemImpl
```

The redis cache is simple case class with a companion object implementing a interface like this :

```
object RedisCache { // some static functions }

case class RedisCache
(
  master : RedisServer,
  slaves : Seq[RedisServer]
)(implicit actorSystem : ActorSystem)
  extends PersistentCache[DeviceKey, BCPPackets] with LazyLogging {
// some code here
}
```

Then to solve the issue, I moved the `redisCache` in the worker and I'm not giving it to the master node :

```
case class Worker
(
  awsBucket : String,
  gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
  replyTo : ActorRef,
  mongoURI : String,
  mongoDBName : String,
  mongoCollectioName : String
) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

// redis cache here now 
val redisCache = ...
```

But with such design, every routee will create a new instance of the redis cache and it's not the expected behaviour. What I want is to have one instance of my redis cache and then share it with all my routees but in a context of a cluster application, it seems to not be  possible so I don't know if it's a design failure or some missing experience with Akka. If anyone met similar issues, I take advices with pleasure !

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `RedisCache` is not that simple. It carries around an `ActorSystem`, which cannot be serialized.

I guess this is because it's containing `RedisClient` instances from - e.g. - [rediscala](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala/blob/master/src/main/scala/redis/Redis.scala) library, and these require an `ActorSystem`.

You will need to abstract from the actor system, and only pass to your workers the bare details of the Redis cluster (i.e. the `RedisServer` objects).

The workers will then instantiate the `RedisClient` themselves - using their `context.system`.

```
case class Worker
(
  awsBucket : String,
  gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
  replyTo : ActorRef,
  redisMaster: RedisServer,
  redisSlaves: Seq[RedisServer],
  mongoURI : String,
  mongoDBName : String,
  mongoCollectioName : String
) extends Actor with ActorLogging {

  val masterSlaveClient = ??? //create from the RedisServer details

}
```

This will allow each worker to put up their own connection with the redis cluster.

Alternatively, if you want to connect only once in your master and share the connection to your workers, you need to pass around the `RedisClientActor` ([source](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala/blob/master/src/main/scala/redis/actors/RedisClientActor.scala) here) that embeds your connection. This is an `ActorRef` and can be shared remotely.

This can be obtained by calling `client.redisConnection`.

The workers can then build an `ActorRequest` around it, for example

```
case class Worker
    (
      awsBucket : String,
      gapMinValueMicroSec : Long,
      replyTo : ActorRef,
      redisConnection: ActorRef,
      mongoURI : String,
      mongoDBName : String,
      mongoCollectioName : String
    ) extends Actor with ActorLogging with ActorRequest {

      // you will need to implement the execution context that ActorRequest needs as well..

      send(redisCommand)

    }
```

Comment: About this solution, it means that each worker will instantiate a redis client ?

Comment: Yes. I have just added one more approach which involves sharing one connection, if that's what you're interested in.

Comment: Yes, I didn't think to alternative. I will give it a try and let you know !

Comment: Just, the main idea of my workers is "pull data from redis and write them in mongodb and S3". If I use an actor embedding the redis client, I have the impression that it won't scale as excepted : the redis actor will receive all the fetching request by my workers.